# How can I prevent these warnings while using ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, combinatorics

I have this code to find all the permutations of a set of letters that form legal words.

```
<<Combinatorica`
Module[{str = "abc", chars, len, r, check},
 chars = Characters[str];
 len = StringLength[str];
 r = Range[len];
 check[n_Integer] := 
  DictionaryLookup[{"BritishEnglish", 
    StringJoin[chars[[UnrankPermutation[n, r]]]]}, 1];
 DistributeDefinitions[check, chars, r];
 ParallelTable[check[i], {i, 1, len!}]]
```

I've verified that, if I replace ParallelTable with Table, I get this:

```
{{}, {}, {}, {"cab"}, {}, {}}
```

With ParallelTable, however, in addition to that result, I also get warnings like these:

```
Part::pspec: Part specification Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[1,{1,2,3}] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.

Part::pspec: Part specification Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[2,{1,2,3}] is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in StringJoin[{a,b,c}[[Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[1,{1,2,3}]]]].

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1 in StringJoin[{a,b,c}[[Combinatorica`UnrankPermutation[2,{1,2,3}]]]].
```

These warnings seem to come from kernel 7 and higher. My guess is that the computation reaches those kernels and there isn't any data left, since there are only 6 permutations, and causes them to spit out those warnings.

Is my understanding correct? How do I prevent these warnings?

Comment: I think `>>` should be `<<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `UnrankPermutation` to `DistributeDefinitions`:

```
DistributeDefinitions[check, chars, r, UnrankPermutation];
```

Comment: Is this because UnrankPermutation comes from the Combinatorica package and isn't a built-in?

Comment: Yes. Using `Get` (`<<`) loads the definitions in the Combinatorica package.  Any you want to use in parallel should have their definitions distributed.

Comment: Better use ``ParallelNeeds["Combinatorica`"]``.